# Unicode Decode Error Python 3

Tags: python, json, decode

I’m getting a `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)`

from this line of code:

```
for fname in os.listdir(configs):   
    if os.path.isfile(fname):  
        with open(fname) as file:
            for line in file:
                print(file)
```

the files in the directory are `JSON` files.

Not sure how to decode json, should I use `import json`? Basically what I want to do is open each file in the given directory and search if there is a specific string present in that file.

Comment: yes, use `json.load()` on each file. BTW your code only works if `configs` is the current directory.

Comment: `open(fname)` opens the file with the *default system encoding*, which in your case is ASCII. Don't do that, specify an explicit encoding, so `open(fname, encoding=some_suitable_encoding). For JSON, that usually is UTF-8.

Comment: Note: https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#json